# "Catalan objects" for which the (common) recurrence is hard to see

Tags: combinatorics

In his book on Catalan numbers, Richard P. Stanley writes that the recurrence $C_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n C_k C_{n-k}$ with $C_0=0$ explains many of the combinatorial interpretations of Catalan numbers. For other "Catalan objects," however, he adds, it can be difficult, if not almost impossible, to see directly why this recurrence holds.

Is there a simple example which illustrates this observation?

Comment: I guess that the author meant the following: if $C_n$ is defined as the number of sub-diagonal paths in a grid, the recurrence is pretty obvious; if $C_n$ is defined as the number of triangulations of a $(n+2)$-gon, it is far less obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think he must be referring to something else though. This is because the recurrence relation is derived from the triangulation, which is the only "Catalan object" that has been introduced at this point (of the book).

Comment: See problems 153 - 193 in [Richard Stanley's collection of bijective proof problems](https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/bij.pdf). These are all about proving interpretations of Catalan numbers, and are labeled with difficulty ratings. Anything [3] or above is pretty hard.

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look.